# What's the best way to drive a browser headlessly on heroku for my purposes?

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, casperjs

Reworded completely:

My vision: Web interface that takes email, student ID, password and desired class as parameters for heroku script. And then once a spot is open, use a webdriver on heroku to register them (using university student portal) and then email them the result (success: you got in, failure: spot was no longer open, will keep trying).

Here's the thing: I have made this on my computer locally and it works like a charm. I used selenium and chromedriver and had a grand old time.

But: How can I get this on heroku? My options seem to be: selenium with ghostdriver, casperjs, phantomjs, Requests (HTTP for HUmans). Screenshots would be nice for debugging but absolutely necessary.

"Best according to what criteria": Scalability, lightweight, easy to build fast (registration is two weeks from October 27 (today) )

Comment: *"best"* according to what criteria? What have you tried, and what is the problem with it?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a browser versus requests or similar library to access web resources (e.g. its using flash or javascript to render the page?)

Comment: Requests certainly can handle this although there may be some trickiness depending on how the website is set up.  (Specifically, I have used requests to handle authentication; in that case, the form used to be submitted required me to grab one or more hidden fields and send along with the fields I needed to fill out).  With that said, jonsharpe (as always) has some valid suggestions for making this a better question that isn't opinon-based and has enough demonstration of what you've tried for folks to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're needing to use Javascript in your application or just find it easier to script a browser than using `requests` or `urllib2`, a headless browser is a good way to go. I'd personally recommend `phantomjs` as it's quite easy to use in node, js, or python.

You'll need a custom buildpack, which is fairly easy to install, [here's a good one](https://github.com/srbartlett/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs-2.0). Note, this requires the cedar stack.

Here's a [bit of info on adding a buildpack](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/running-a-headless-browser-on-heroku/97/2).

And here's example setup code from the README of the buildpack repo:

```
$ heroku create --stack cedar-14 --buildpack https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi
$ echo "https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt" >> .buildpacks
$ echo "https://github.com/srbartlett/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs-2.0.git" >> .buildpacks
$ cat <<EOT >> Aptfile
libicu52
libjpeg8
libfontconfig
libwebp5
EOT

$ git push heroku master
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: So now, can I use webdriver.PhantomJS() without an issue or do I still have to put the phantomjs bin somewhere in /app?

Comment: Update: I successfully used PhantomJS on heroku with the custom build pack. Zero problems. What a time to be alive. Thanks everyone.