# Python: Scrape JavaScript table and save result as csv file without opening browser

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

**Python: Scraping web-table and save data to a CSV file**
**:** The code below works perfectly but how can I achieve the same objective of scraping the table without opening a browser? i.e. Run process underground. The code is as follows;

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import contextlib
import csv
import json

@contextlib.contextmanager
def quitting(browser):
    yield browser
    browser.close()
    browser.quit()

with quitting(webdriver.Chrome()) as driver:
    url = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/statistics/total_points"
    driver.get(url)
    id = 1;
    data = []
    idlist = [id]
    for tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="ism-table ism-table--el"]//tr'):
        tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        if tds:
            data.append([id]+[td.text for td in tds])
            #data[0] = id
            id = id+1
            #idlist = [id+1]
            #n = len(data)
            outfile=open('./result.csv','w')
            wr = csv.writer(outfile, dialect='excel')
            wr.writerows(data)
            print(data)
```

Comment: Rather than using selenium, you might be able to request the page content with the requests package for Python: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: use phantomjs instead of chrome, it is a headless browser. other option is to use requests module.

Comment: @yosemite_k PhantomJS is probably closer to the solution OP is looking for :)

Comment: If i may ask, will the headless browsers work on a python server? I can see requirement for operating system when downloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the quickest approach is to replace chrome driver with [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)

```
with quitting(webdriver.PhantomJS()) as driver:
    # initiates a phantomjs headless browser browser, runs underground


with quitting(webdriver.Chrome()) as driver:
    # initiates a chrome browser the browser is visible on the screen
```

Comment: I can see there is  Phantomjs for windows, mac and linux? What happens when the code is uploaded on python server? Do i need to put all file for versions?

Comment: depends on the server. most porbably you will have to read this. https://gist.github.com/julionc/7476620

Comment: I have obtained information on how to run this on server from the link below: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351653/whats-the-best-way-to-drive-a-browser-headlessly-on-heroku-for-my-purposes

Answer (score 0):

You can use PhantomJS as a driver in stead of chrome to open a headless browser. You ca download it from here: http://phantomjs.org/download.html, add exe to Python35-32 folder and then you use it just like chrome driver but instead you write:

```
with quitting(webdriver.PhantomJS()) as driver:
```